# Create a list of matrices given initial list and specific transformation in R

Tags: arrays, r, list, matrix, lapply

I have a list of length 200 `mylist`, where each element is an integer list.

Then I want to create a table for each element, and eventually create a list with the very same length, where each element is a matrix.

Let's say for the sake of simplicity that my list is `mylist = c(1001:1200)`.

now I want to create a transformation for each element, for example:
given that

```
set.seed(222)
a =  sample( length(temp), 10 )
b =  sample( length(temp), 10 )
c =  211
```

where `a` and `b` are lists of length 10, I want to apply

```
(a * mylist[i] + b) %% c
```

in  each element (out of 200) for my original list

I tried using two for loops but it does not do the job.

```
temp <- vector(mode='array', length =1)

for (i in 1:length(mylist) ) {
  for (j in 1:10) {
    temp[[i]] =( a[j] * mylist[[i]] + b[j] ) %% c
  }
}
```

particularly I get a list of length 200, where for each element of mylist (1:200) I get result from the following transformation

```
 (a[10]*mylist[[1]]+b[10])%%c
 (a[10]*mylist[[2]]+b[10])%%c
```

...

etc, meaning that it takes into consideration only the last (out of 10) elements of lists a and b. (it is like `for (j in 1:10)` is not running, but takes `j=10`

Any idea how to implement that?

Comment: Your `mylist` seems to be a `vector` instead of `list`,  Also, what is `temp`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are only defining the element i of `temp`. That's why you only obtain the last value, because it re-writes. Try this:

```
 temp <- array(NA, c(length(mylist),10))

 for (i in 1:length(mylist) ) {
   for (j in 1:10) {
     temp[[i,j]] =( a[j] * mylist[[i]] + b[j] ) %% c
   }
 }
```